# Python MOOCS - after I break, why does it not go back to the outer for loop?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    l1=[]
    l3=[]
    while True:
        pts=input("Exam points and exercises completed: ")
        if pts=="":
            break
        x=pts.split()
        l1.append(int(x[0])+int(x[1])//10)
        l3.append(int(x[0]))
    print("Statistics: ")
    print("Points average:", sum(l1)/len(l1))
    print("Pass percentage:","{:.1f}".format(fail(l1,l3)))
    distn=grade_distn(l1,l3)
    print("Grade distribution:")
    num=5
    for i in distn:
        print(f" {num}: {'*' * i}")
        num=num-1

def fail(l1,l3):
    suc=0
    for i in range(0,len(l1)):
        if l3[i]>=10 and l1[i]>14:
            suc+=1
    return (suc/len(l1))*100

def grade_distn(l1,l3):
    distn=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
    boundary=[0,15,18,21,24,28]
    for i in range(0,len(l1)-1):
        for j in range(0,6):
            if l1[i]<boundary[j]:
                distn[-j]+=1
                break
    return distn
    
main()
```

basically, in the function grade_distn(), after I do distn[-j]+=1 and break, I thought it would only break the inner loop and then go directly back to the outer loop and then traverse through the inner loop again. however, when i put my code into a python visualizer, after the "break", it goes to the "for i in range(0,len(l1)-1):" and then immediately goes to the "return distn". i'm trying to understand why it doesnt go back to the for j in range part.

Comment: `break` does only break out of the inner loop (See [this minimal example](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPIdpQR8FIR8E41opLAQhA4lkQcQOgBBAbG0ClQKCgKDOvRCNTRyFLEy6WmQbUYWerYGigoKWQiVALAklFqYnZ//8DAA)). Are you sure this didn't happen on the last iteration of the outer loop?